# Backup Exec 16 Service Account permissions

Tags: permissions, readynas, backup-exec

i am trying to set up a new storage pool in Backup Exec 16 but am having some issues with the service account permissions.

[image]

The service account I am using as part of the Domain Admins group and is currently being used for other backup jobs with no problems.
The storage location is on a Netgear ReadyNAS and I have configured a test share for the purposes of this trial. The ReadyNAS is running firmware 6.7.5. In the share I have set what I presumed to be the correct permissions (read/write for the service account), I have also altered the Local Security Policy on the backup server to fall in line with the recommendations from Veritas (https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.TECH23689)
Despite adding these permissions, when I try to finish the storage wizard, I get a message saying that the service account does not have read/write permissions set on the storage location.

[image]

There are other shares on the ReadyNAS which are working with no issues.

I have ensured that the service account has the correct logon type and credentials in the services.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just this ReadyNAS have it's own user authentication system by chance?  When I got my Drobo I was shocked to learn that by default, the guest user, wouldn't allow me to access the files on it and I would have to mount the network drive using a username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Schoolboy Error!

I had set Share permissions via the NAS but had not set NTFS permissions on the share!

D'oh!!!!!

Comment: I had set the correct share permissions on the NAS so users/groups could access the share but had not set NTFS permissions via Windows so the BackupExec service account I was trying to use did not have access to the directory.